# How to disable an Autocomplete textbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to enable/disable some fields depending on a checkbox and combobox conditions. I am using JQuery. It works fine for normal textboxes, but not for the autocomlete.

**HTML**

```html
ctr:txtBox code="miles"

aut:Autocomplete code="replPerson"
```

**Javascript**

```
$("[code=miles]").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //works fine
$("[code=miles]").removeAttr("disabled");      //works fine

$("[code=replPerson]").attr("disabled", "disabled"); //does not work
$("[code=liters]").removeAttr("disabled"); //does not work
```

tried these variants as well (none of them worked for me):

```
//document.getElementById("txtPersona").readOnly = true; 
//$("[code=replPerson]").prop("readonly", true);
//$("[code=replPerson]").attr("readonly", "true");
//$("[code=replPerson]").attr("enabled", "false");
//$("[code=replPerson]").attr("class", "disabled");
```

Comment: Are you using some type of library? I don't recognise the ctr:txtBox or aut:Autocomplete. Please update your question to have usable html.

Comment: aut:Autocomplete is defined in Autocomplete.ascx

Comment: should I post code here?

Comment: You can edit your question and add the actual HTML, or if you want to create a full working JS example, you can create and link to one from an external site like https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla. The HTML you've provided appears to be ASP code which requires a server to run and render true HTML. The final goal is for us to be able to easily reproduce your problem and help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example